# Flutter: Create file with absolute path in windows

Tags: flutter, windows, dart

I want to create a file with an absolute file path on Windows, but a FileSystemException error occurs.

```
var path = "C:/Users/User/Documents/myapp/";
File(path).createSync(recursive: true);
```

I've already tried to use backslash with the same error.

The error message is "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

How can I fix this?
Thank you very much!

Edit: I've just found out that I can create files, but no directories... So just deleting the last '/' works. However, I need to create this directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Directory class, NOT the File class to create directories.